# Как узнать поля наследника, имея базовый класс

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создаю системы вещей в RPG.
Есть несколько типов вещей(одежда, еда, мусор и т.д.).
В сумке хранятся только массив Item, т.к. мы не знаем какое количество каких предметов будет. Как получить доступ к полям наследников от Item? Или может есть другое решение проблемы вещей разного типа.

```
public class GearItem: Item
{
    public int Level;
    public GearType Type;
    public Stats Stats
}

public class FoodItem: Item
{
    public AttributeStat Attribute;
}

public class Item
{
    public int SlotId;
    public Texture Texture;
}


public class Inventory
{
    public Item[] Items;

    public Inventory(Item[] items)
    {
        Items = items;
    }

    public GearItem GetGear()
    {
        // вернуть любой gearItem
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (item is GearItem gearItem) return gearItem;` где `item` имеет тип `Item`.

Comment: `item.GetType()`, далее просто проверять, каким типом является предмет и возвращать нужный, либо `Object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2)`